# Node.js socket ended by other party

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a TCP server based on Node.js. When new sockets are connected, I wrap them in a client object:

```
    net.createServer(function(socket){
        socket.setEncoding("utf8");
        socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ':' + socket.remotePort;
        var client = cm.create(socket);
    }).listen(this.settings.port);
```

When the client disconnects, how can I prevent myself from writing to the socket? I know there are events such as 'close', 'error', and 'end', but I cannot figure out how these will help me.

As far as I understand, these events will only trigger when I try to write data to the closed socket. But by that time, the error is thrown....

Comment: Even if you prevent yourself to write to the socket after you recognized that the connection was closed, you still could get an error, if the stream was e.g. buffering the data before writing, or if both closing and writing happens at the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that *just handling* the error event itself prevents the unhandlered error exception. Who would have thought?

```
    client.socket.on('error', function(){
        console.log("CLIENT HAS ERRORED")
    });
```

This prevents the node app from dying.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this pseudocode:

```
var active = true;

var connection = createConnection();
connection.onExit(function() { active = false; });

while (active){
  connection.talk();
}
```

So your communication thread shares a variable that is accessible by the callback that occurs when the socket shuts down. That way they can communicate.